# pyqt eventfilter detects more than a single press

Tags: python, pyqt, eventfilter

I'm using `pyqt` and designed a window with `QTextEdit`. I added an event, but when I press enter it detects more than a single press. For example; when I press enter I want it to print 1. It does print 1, but not one time three times.

This is the eventfilter func:

```
def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent and event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return):
            if(not str(self.lineEdit.toPlainText()).isspace() and str(self.lineEdit.toPlainText())!="" ):
                data="YOU: " +str(self.lineEdit.toPlainText())
                self.my_socket.send(data)
                label=QtGui.QLabel()
                label.setText(data)
                label.setWordWrap(True)
                self.chat_layout.v_layout_container.addWidget(label)
                label.show()
                self.lineEdit.clear()
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Comment: Add the code that you use..

Comment: This question is totally unclear. Here is [how to create a minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).